# Can't install Tortoise SVN 1.7.3 on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, permissions, svn, windows-registry

I'm trying to install just the Tortoise SVN client on my windows server 2008 R2 and get the following error message:

```
Could not create key:
\Software\Classes\Folder\shellex\ColumnHandlers\{3035-1349-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}.
Verify that you have sufficient access to that key, or contact your support personnel.
```

which seems to indicate a permissions problem in the registry, but I'd rather avoid changing permissions in there out of fears of unintended consequences. I'm using a local 'administrator' account, and have disabled UAC (user access control) based on some other postings, but that doesn't solve this registry problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Does Administrators have full control to that registry key?

Answer (score 0):

have you right-clicked on the installer -> run as administrator?

even with UAC disabled and running as a local admin, windows server 2008 requires you to elevate certain actions for them to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to update on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 SP1 without issue. I am a local admin on the server. I did **not** have to right-click and choose "run as administrator", but did have to acknowledge the UAC warnings as they came up.